# how to automatically display first pic of a slideshow

Tags: javascript, html, css, slideshow

[the html css and javascript](https://codepen.io/uemmanzz/pen/OJLgRZb) I have to press the button in order to show the slideshow other than automatically loading the first picture

```
        <!-- Slideshow container -->
        <div class="slideshow-container">[The html,css and js][1]

    <!-- Full-width images with number and caption text -->
        <div class="mySlides active">
        <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
        <img src="slideshow/img1.jpg" style="width:100%">
        <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
        </div>

        <div class="mySlides fade">
        <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
        <img src="slideshow/img2.jpg" style="width:100%">
        <div class="text">Caption Two</div>
        </div>

        <div class="mySlides fade">
        <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
        <img src="slideshow/img3.jpg" style="width:100%">
        <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
        </div>

    <!-- Next and previous buttons -->
        <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
        <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
        </div>
        <br>

        <!-- The dots/circles -->
        <div style="text-align:center">
        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
        </div>
```

it displays nothing, i have to press  next button in order to show

[enter link description here](https://codepen.io/uemmanzz/pen/OJLgRZb)

Comment: Can you please include your javascript and css? Will help if we can see the problem.

Comment: I suggest you add that link to your question, will make it easier for others to read.

Comment: Once the src of imgs was correctly setted with valid paths (urls), just worked: https://codepen.io/danimai/pen/dybROvp